# Not detecting service worker

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I am struggling to understand why the service worker isn't functional.

I get no console errors, I have added all files within the folder into the sw.js ( `cache.addAll([...` ) and nothing.

edit* I can't add full html because of the post limit but I also use

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>`

does this interfere with service workers?

here is the code:

```js
const CACHE_NAME = `test`;

// Use the install event to pre-cache all initial resources.
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    cache.addAll([
      '/',
      '/index.html',
      '/favicon.ico',
      '/icon512.png',
      '/manifest.json',
      '/style.css',
      '/sw.js'
    ]);
  })());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith((async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);

    // Get the resource from the cache.
    const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
    if (cachedResponse) {
      return cachedResponse;
    } else {
        try {
          // If the resource was not in the cache, try the network.
          const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request);

          // Save the resource in the cache and return it.
          cache.put(event.request, fetchResponse.clone());
          return fetchResponse;
        } catch (e) {
          // The network failed.
        }
    }
  })());
});
```

adding the service working within the .html file using :

```
 </body>


    <script>
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', { scope: '/' });
        }
    </script>
    
    
</html>
```

Here is the manifest.json :

```
{
    "lang": "en-US",
    "name": "Form lemon",
    "short_name": "Form lemon",
    "description": "A dynamic form...",
    "start_url": "/",
    "background_color": "#2f3d58",
    "theme_color": "#2f3d58",
    "orientation": "any",
    "display": "standalone",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/icon512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you're not getting console errors, how do you know that the service worker isn't working?

Comment: @grimsteel the service worker is not registered in the application developer tools. However it seems to work when I use the alternate local server (node.js) and also clearing the nodes.